# Touch on ar Object in Ar.js

Tags: javascript, model, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I have a question concerning touch detection on ar objects. 
I use A-Frame with Ar.js

In my Project, I have a globe which can be rotated. 
Now I wanna add country-specific "markers", which should also be objects.

I tried:

AFRAME.registerComponent('markerhandler', {

```
init: function() {
    const animatedMarker = document.querySelector("#hiro");
    const aEntity = document.querySelector("#globe");

    animatedMarker.addEventListener('click', function(ev, target){
        console.log("hi")

    });
```

But I just recognized the click event anywhere on the display ...

I also tried using a raycaster from a-frame, but also with no detection :(

Has anyone a better idea/reference projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a-frame versions earlier than 1.0.0, you can just do

```
<a-marker cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
     <a-box click-listener-component></a-box>
</a-marker>
<a-entity camera></a-camera>
```

---

but since 1.0.0 it's not working, at least with [the example from the docs](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js#marker-tracking).

From what i've noticed, the [raycaster direction](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/cursor.js#L225) is different when using a-frame `0.9.2` and `1.0.0`. Weird thing is, when using vanilla a-frame (without ar.js), it seems to be working just fine. Looks like a `ar.js` thing.

Anyway, if you substitute the cursors direction calculation with an older version of the `THREE.Vector3` [unproject](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/8bad3a4942cf9464bf620367608dbd6e5f9bf8f9):

```
// instead of this:
applyMatrix4( camera.projectionMatrixInverse ).applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );

// use this
let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
applyMatrix4( matrix.getInverse( camera.projectionMatrix ) ).applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );
```

The cursor component is working again. You can check it out in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/~aframear-cursor)

Comment: This works beautifully, and really should be baked-in to the AR.js version available online.

Comment: I guess i could make a component out of it